# How can i render all of my prints of for loop in html div in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to print the ticket variable in to html file using Flask and jinja2 but when i try to run the code i recive this error: local variable 'ticket' referenced before assignment

I have to do it this way because I would like to have a sort of log on the html page for the user to see when the loop is running. This is the code, any help is welcome. Thanks

```
for i in file:
            f = i.split(";")
            id_ticket = f[0]
            data_apertura = f[1]
            data_chiusura = f[2]
            if doppioni(id_ticket):
                print("Ticket: " + id_ticket + " già caricato nel sito")
                ticket = print("Ticket: " + id_ticket + " già caricato nel sito")
            else:
                print("Ticekt caricato nel Sito")
                ticket = print("Ticket: " + id_ticket + " caricato nel sito")
                log.write(id_ticket+";"+data_apertura+";"+data_chiusura+";"+"\n")
            


return render_template("home.html", name=current_user.username, ticket=ticket)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a print statement to `ticket`. Instead, you can do

```py
ticket = "Ticket: " + id_ticket + " già caricato nel sito"
print(ticket)
```

so in your `render_template` statement you'll have a string to pass in as a `ticket` parameter

Comment: Unfortunately same error. Even if I change the variable and print it in the loop and leave the render_template unchanged. So i tested the the loop without render parameter in render_template and work.